# SQLite: Individual tables per user or one table for them all?

Tags: database, sqlite

I've already designed a website which uses an SQLite database. Instead of using one large table, I've designed it so that when a user signs up, a individual table is created for them. Each user will possibly use several hundreds of records. I done this because I thought it would be easier to structure and access.

I found on other questions on this site that one table is better than using many tables for each user.

Would it be worth redesigning my site so that instead of having many tables, there would be one large table? The current method of mine seems to work well though it is still in development so I'm not sure how well it would stack up in a real environment.

The question is: Would changing the code so that there is one large database instead of many individual ones be worth it in terms of performance, efficiency, organisation and space?

**SQLite: Creating a user's table.**

```
CREATE TABLE " + name + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, subject TEXT, topic TEXT, questionNumber INTEGER, question TEXT, answer TEXT, color TEXT)
```

**SQLite: Adding an account to the accounts table.**

```
"INSERT INTO accounts (name, email, password, activated) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (name, email, password, activated,)
```

Please note that I'm using python with Flask if it makes any difference.

---

**EDIT**

I am also aware that there are questions like this already, however none state whether the advantages or disadvantages will be worth it.

Comment: Hundreds of rows is nothing. How do the existing tables differ?

Comment: @Tichodroma They all use the same fields. The only real difference is the content.

Comment: Then your existing design is bad design. Use one table and a field that identifies the user who is the owner of a row.

Comment: @moffeltje Why? This sounds like an even worse design.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the DDL ( `CREATE TABLE`)  statements of your table(s). Then, perhaps, we can tell what is good or bad.

Comment: @moffeltje The user table just has simple data such as a primary key, username, password, email etc. I could do that however I don't know if the advantages are worth the time.

Comment: @Tichodroma I mean normalization. Just like stackoverflow has a table Users and a table Posts.

Comment: What happens if you'll have to alter data structure? Maybe add a constraint or a column? Do you change each table then? If you have to change it in more than one place - it's a bad design.

Comment: @ŁukaszR. Yes that's a good point. Would there not be an easy way to change the data structure of a number of tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an object oriented language, would you make a class for every user? Or would you have an instance of a class for each user?

Having one table per user is a really bad design.

- You can't search messages based on any field that isn't the username. With your current solution, how would you find all messages for a certain `questionNumber`?
- You can't join with the messages tables. You have to make two queries, one to find the table name and one to actually query the table, which requires two round-trips to the database server.
- Each user now has their own table schema. On an upgrade, you have to apply your schema migration to every messages table, and God help you if some of the tables are inconsistent with the rest.
- It's effectively impossible to have foreign keys pointing to your messages table. You can't specify the table that the foreign key column points to, because it won't be the same.
- You can have name conflicts with your current setup. What if someone registers with the username `accounts`? Admittedly, this is easy to fix by adding a `user_` prefix, but still something to keep in mind.
- SQL injection vulnerabilities. What if I register a user named `lol; DROP TABLE accounts; --`? Query parameters, the primary way of preventing such attacks, don't work on table names.

I could go on.

Please merge all of the tables, and read up on database normalization.