# database, a table for each users or a big table?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

I just start to learn database, in designing a database, I notice that a lot of recommendations, such as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982939/sqlite-individual-tables-per-user-or-one-table-for-them-all), suggests NOT to use one table per user, but keep all data in a big table and do a query when needed. But I still do NOT understand, because it seems that under a lot of situations, one table per user seems much efficient.

Suppose I have a database for 10,000 customers for them to track their orders. Each of customers will have very few orders, like around 10. In this way, every customer logs in, you will have to go through a big table to fetch data for this customer, however, if you keep each table per user, you can directly get what the customer need.

Another example, a restaurant information system tracks all restaurants' menu (say, in [foodname, price] pair), since each restaurant has different number of dishes, you can't really put each menu in one row, you can only make a huge table with [foodname,price,restaurant] rows. But there are a lot of restaurants, so when a user needs the menu of a certain restaurant, you'll need to go through the data of all restaurants, obviously inefficient.

For both these two examples, I can't think of a good way to design a database if I don't want to create each table per user. So my question is this:
If we want to avoid each table per user design, how should we design a database for these kinds of situations?

Answer (score 2):

Sql databases are designed exactly for the types of scenarios you are suggesting. They can handle millions or billions of rows extremely efficiently. The complications of trying to partition every customer into a separate table are vast.

The only thing you need to worry about is that you have indexes on your table so that you do not have to scan through that billion records to find the ones applicable to your customer.

Once the indexes are in place then all of your example scenarios become simple and efficient queries.

Answer (score 1):

Databases are designed to do exactly the kinds of lookups you're describing efficiently, even if all users are in a single table. As long as you create an index by user ID (or have the user ID as part of the primary key), then the database will keep the table sorted by user ID, so it can find any particular user efficiently using binary search.

"Tables" don't mean exactly what you think they mean either. Tables are meant to be used to logically group data in ways that are useful for the programmer. In theory, any database you use could just consist of one big table, but it's generally easier to reason about a database if you know that rows of the User table look like this, while rows of the Message table (or whatever) look like that. In fact, many databases only actually have one big underlying "table" in which all the data lives. So, whether two users are in the "same table" or "different tables" often doesn't matter at all from an efficiency standpoint.

Database management software is written based on the assumption that you'll have a relatively small number of tables (dozens, maybe hundreds in extreme cases). So go with whatever your database's documentation recommends.